# Is there a way to regenerate clouds that move across a screen?

Tags: java, graphics, processing

I am putting together a game I had an idea for in Processing, and I am trying to fix the background first.

I've created an array of cloud objects that move in the background, and I want to be able to regenerate them as they move off screen.

Each cloud is made up of a series of circles, each with their own x position and y offset. They can move across the screen OK; the problem arises when creating the code to regenerate them. I've tried to create an if statement to check the x position of the last circle in the series.

```
/////////////MAIN SETUP////////////////

PVector screenSize;
PVector windowPosition;
PVector windowSize;

void setup() {
  size(1400,900,P3D);
  smooth();

  screenSize = new PVector(width, height);
  windowPosition = new PVector(0,0);

  frameRate(60);

  loadEnvironment();
}

void draw() {
  background(134,224,255);
  drawEnvironment();
}

///////////////FOR THE CLOUD SETUP/////////////////


int cloudNumber;

Cloud[] totalclouds;

void loadEnvironment()
{
  cloudNumber = round(random(5,25));

  totalclouds = new Cloud[cloudNumber];
  for(int i = 0; i<cloudNumber; i++)
  {
   totalclouds[i] = new Cloud();
  }
};

///////////////////////////////////////
void drawEnvironment()
{
  for(int i = 0; i<cloudNumber; i++)
  {
    totalclouds[i].update();
  }
};

/////////////////////////////////////////
class Cloud
{
  float xPos;
  float yPos;

  float yTop;
  float yBottom;

  float xVelocityMin;
  float xVelocityMax;
  float xVelocity;

  float screenStart = 0;
  float screenEnd = width;

  int cloudSize = round(random(1,4));

  float[] xPosition = new float[cloudSize];
  float[] yPositionOffset = new float[cloudSize];
  float[] xDiam = new float[cloudSize];
  float[] yDiam = new float[cloudSize];

  float xDiameter = random(40,50);
  float yDiameter = random(40,50);
  float yOffset = random(10,20);

  float overlap = xDiameter/5;

  //'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

  Cloud (){
    xPos = random(width);
    yPos = random(windowPosition.y, 350);

    xPosition[0] = xPos;
    if (xPosition.length>1)
       for(int i = 1; i<cloudSize; i++)
       {
       xPosition[i] = xPosition[i-1] + (xDiameter/2) + overlap;
       }
    for (int i = 0; i<cloudSize; i++)
    {
      yPositionOffset[i] = yOffset;
    }

    xVelocityMin = 0.3;
    xVelocityMax = 0.6;
    xVelocity = random(xVelocityMin, xVelocityMax);
  }

  //''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  void move() {
    for(int i = 0; i<cloudSize; i++)
    {
    xPosition[i] += xVelocity;
    }
  }

  //''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  void createNewClouds() {
    int lastItem = xPosition.length - 1;

    if (xPosition[lastItem]>screenEnd);
    {
      xPosition[0] = screenStart;
      if (xPosition.length>1)
       for(int i = 1; i<cloudSize; i++)
       {
       xPosition[i] = xPosition[i-1] + (xDiameter/2) + overlap;
       }
      for (int i = 0; i<cloudSize; i++)
      {
       yPositionOffset[i] = yOffset;
      }

    xVelocityMin = 0.3;
    xVelocityMax = 0.6;
    xVelocity = random(xVelocityMin, xVelocityMax);
    }
  }

  //''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  void display() {
    for(int i = 0; i<cloudSize; i++)
    {
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(xPosition[i], yPos + yPositionOffset[i], xDiameter, yDiameter);
    }
  }

  //''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  void update() {
    move();
    display();
    createNewClouds();
  }
}
```

Without the regeneration code, it works fine - clouds move as expected. With the code, clouds have a starting position of `x=0`. Why is this the case if there's an if statement? And why don't they move?

Comment: A "conceptual" idea is to group all the elements within a "virtual" container.  Each child of the container is offset in relation to the container itself (ie `0x0` is the container's top left corner), then you move the "container" itself. When you come to render the clouds, you would offset the graphics context (ie translate it) by the containers position, then render the children.  So technically, the children never move, only the container does

Comment: Why does your `Cloud` class contain an array of positions? What does each of those positions represent?

Comment: The array of positions is for the extra circles in the cloud, to build up the whole thing. I'd seen the idea to move the container, but I thought I'd try and get it to work this way. Since this way is proving to be a bit tricky, I may go with the container idea.